# Gradle: Why do I have to add repository needed by project dependency?

Tags: java, gradle

Let's say I have two projects, `Main` and `Infrastructure`, both built with Gradle `4.10.3`. `Infrastructure` declares `SomeOtherDependency` in its dependencies:

```
repositories {
    // jcenter is needed for "SomeOtherDependency"
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.othercompany.someotherdependency:8.2.16'
}
```

And in turn, `Main` declares `Infrastructure` as its dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.myprojects.infrastructure:1.22.0'
    
}
```

`Main` is failing to build when this is the state of things:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/gsonfire/GsonFireBuilder

**Unless** I include `jcenter()` in `Main`'s dependencies as well. If I do that, all works well. But I suspect this is not how Gradle dependencies are supposed to work?

I know that that `GsonFireBuilder` is a class that `SomeOtherDependency` depends on, but why can't it be reached if `jcenter()` does not appear in the repositories of the project consuming `Infrastructure`?

BTW: it doesn't matter if I use `compile`/`api`/`implementation` when declaring the `SomeOtherDependency` dependency.

I'm surely misunderstanding some things here: how can I rid `Main` of the responsibility to declare dependencies of *its* dependency, `Infrastructure`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing two concepts here. A dependency is another package you need (the "what"). A repository is a place to find dependencies (the "from where"). A dependency may be found in more than one repository.

For example, you could run your local repository and cache all packages you ever used. If repositories and dependencies were tied together, you'd have to upgrade all your dependencies and point them to your cache repository. In fact, if dependencies of dependencies specified their repositories, you'd have to manually dig through all of those and point them to your cache repository. That would almost defeat the purpose of automatic dependency management. Hence you specify repositories and dependencies separately.

See [the diagram on dependency management in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency-mgmt-in-gradle): local path, Gradle cache, repositories in the cloud --- adjusting dependencies each time would be a pain.

With that, you probably don't need to specify the repository your dependency uses. You just need to configure *any* repository that has the required dependencies of your dependency.

Comment: Maybe I’m being slow, pardon my persistence: so when I specify a dependency which depends on whatever other dependency, it is my responsibility (the project using the dependency) to specify the repository of dependency-of-dependency?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The assumption here is that all dependencies are available from public repositories. But you as the person making the final build can decide which repository you use. Maybe you dislike one or prefer another? Or your company could run its own repository, where all packages have been manually inspected for security problems, and all code can only be built with those packages. Does that make sense?